# Can't access subfolders on FTP server using Apache Commons FTPClient

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I want to download files which are in subfolder on FTP server but I see that my client can't access subfolders.

I wrote simple code to list all files in subfolder:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

    ftpClient.connect(HOST, PORT);
    ftpClient.login(USER, PASS);
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

    FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles("/archive");
    int length = files.length;
    System.out.println("Number of files: " + length);

    ftpClient.logout();
    ftpClient.disconnect();
}
```

But length of `files` array is zero.

When I run this program on main directory files are listed properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is ok. It should work on *most servers*. Your code will send this command to the server:

```
LIST /archive
```

That's correct (assuming the server uses this path syntax [slash] to refer to a subfolder of the root folder).

---

But some (obscure) servers have problems with arguments passed to the `LIST` command.

Try this code instead:

```
ftpClient.cwd("archive");
FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();
```

The above will send:

```
CWD archive
LIST
```

---

Another approach worth trying is removing the leading slash, as the server may use a different path delimiter:

```
FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles("archive");
```